# How to prevent Windows Auto-update from force rebooting

Tags: windows, windows-10

Windows 10 has been force rebooting on me for the last two days -- resulting in loss of work and disruption of work. Needless to say, arbitrary force reboot is exacerbating and harmful.

What settings can I adjust in order to ensure that Windows 10 will not ever force reboot?

I have Windows 10 Education Version 1909.

Before the first of the 2 recent force reboot, there had not been any force reboot for several months. (Yes, it started off with way more and way worse.) The registry setting at the time in

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU
```

was

```
AUOptions = 5
NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers = 1
NoAutoUpdate = 0
ScheduledInstallDay = 1
ScheduledInstallTime = 4
```

The first force reboot had the description below. (Event ID 1074.)

```
The process C:\Windows\System32\usocoreworker.exe (DESKTOP-U7DHLNI) has initiated the restart of computer DESKTOP-U7DHLNI on behalf of user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM for the following reason: Operating System: Service pack (Planned)
 Reason Code: 0x80020010
 Shut-down Type: restart
 Comment:
```

It occurred at 6:02AM.

When I discovered the force reboot, I changed `AUOptions` to 4 because [this page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-restart#registry-keys-used-to-manage-restart) seems to suggest that the `NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers` setting can only work with `AUOptions` set to 4. By all means, force reboot of any kind is annoying. I can manage my own security risk. But if reboot only occurs without any user logged in, it wouldn't cause loss of work in my setting.

Yet again, today at 4:25AM, my computer was forced reboot again. (It seems the reboot did not come from a user-scheduled policy?) Event Description below.  (Event ID 1074.)

```
The process C:\Windows\servicing\TrustedInstaller.exe (DESKTOP-U7DHLNI) has initiated the restart of computer DESKTOP-U7DHLNI on behalf of user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM for the following reason: Operating System: Upgrade (Planned)
 Reason Code: 0x80020003
 Shut-down Type: restart
```

I happened to be physically using my computer at the time. The shutdown occurred almost immediately at that timestamp. 3 minutes before though, there was the following event: (Event ID 1074.)

```
The process C:\Windows\System32\usocoreworker.exe (DESKTOP-U7DHLNI) has initiated the restart of computer DESKTOP-U7DHLNI on behalf of user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM for the following reason: Operating System: Service pack (Planned)
 Reason Code: 0x80020010
 Shut-down Type: restart
 Comment:
```

How do I prevent Windows 10 from force rebooting my computer?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105270/discussion-on-question-by-argyll-how-to-prevent-windows-auto-update-from-force-r).